# Create a non standard weekly date range autofill in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I am working on a monthly spreadsheet of our daily takings.
I need one line for a sunday, monday and tuesday but two lines for wednesday, thursday, friday and saturday.  I can't seem to hit the magic formula to copy this down the column.

```
Wed 1/Oct/2014
Wed 1/Oct/2014
Thur 2/Oct/2014
Thur 2/Oct/2014
Fri 3/Oct/2014
Fri 3/Oct/2014
Sat 4/Oct/2014
Sat 4/Oct/2014
Sun 5/Oct/2014
Mon 6/Oct/2014
Tue 7/Oct/2014
```

I am sure there is a simple answer but I am stumped.

Comment: Its for a monthly spreadsheet of cash takings for our business.  It's quiet on sun/mon/tues so there is only 1 cash register opened.  The other days there are two cash registers opened so need two lines for these days.  Sorry I don't understand algorithms

Comment: You need a line for the 10th of each month, except when it falls on Wed - Sat, in which case you need 2 lines? ah nevermind, this is dd/mm/yy - sorry.

Comment: Oops - confusion may arise in my original post it's meant to be - 1 Oct 2014, 2 Oct 2014, etc  In Australia dd/mm/yy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use the weekday function which will give you what day of the week it is.  The default format is 1=Sunday through 7=Saturday

In A3

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A2)>=4,A2+0.5,A2+1)
```

If the day of the week is Wednesday through saturday add half a day otherwise add a whole day.  With no time shown it doesn't matter if the time is 0:00 or 12:00 which is what adding 0.5 effectively does.

If time matters you would have to look at the two rows above which is less ideal.

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance.  Works great ... AND saves me soooo much time!  Cheers